# Can I exchange a native ASUS X551M hard drive and a Toshiba Canvio Connect II external drive?

Tags: hard-drive

My ASUS X551M laptop hard disk suffered a failure. Instead of buying a new laptop, I bought a Toshiba Canvio Connect II external hard drive, and I plan to switch the two. That way, I supposedly might even be able to salvage some of the data on the damaged original drive, by plugging it into my computer via usb.

Would the two fit in each others' respective slots? They look like they have different formats.[image: The two hard drives]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top drive has a serial ATA connector while the bottom drive has a mini-USB 3.0 connector.  Since both drives have their connectors integrated into their controller boards, you cannot switch the two.

Comment: Do you think I could buy a new hard disk that I could use to replace the old one?

Comment: Buy a standard 2.5 inch sata hdd or ssd. If your old drive is a 7mm  thick drive, buy a 7mm thick drive.